# About MySQL module in node.js and concurrent connections to mySQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, concurrency

I am planning to deploy an Angular website with node.js backend and mySQL database to a shared hosting that support it. The hosting website has a limit of maximum 25 concurrent connections to mySQL database at a time.

I am using mySQL module in node.js to access the database. Here is a pseudo-code that represents the structure:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

app.get('/query/:id', function (req, res) {
    let mc = mysql.createConnection(...);
    mc.connect((err)=>{
       ...
       mc.query(...);}
    );});
```

Now what I am not sure about is: If the maximum concurrent connection limit to the database is reached, where will the error generate? Will the error come from this step:

> mysql.createConnection()

, or this step:

> mc.connect()

,or this step:

> mc.query()

Also, where is the most appropriate place to deal with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation for error handling: 
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#error-handling

You would see an error in both the `mc.connect()` and `mc.query` callbacks, however in your case above it probably wouldn't make it to the `mc.query` since that is inside of the `mc.connect` callback.